# Julia: Append an element to an array of custom types

Tags: arrays, julia

Appending an element to an array in Julia works like this:

```
v = Array{Int32, 1}(0)
append!(v, 1)
append!(v, 2)
println(v)  # prints: Int32[1,2]
```

When I try this with a custom type

```
type Node
    label::String
    value::Int32
end
nodes = Array{Node, 1}(0)
append!(nodes, Node("a", 42))
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching length(::Node)
```

I assume I have to 'implement' the `length` method but do not know how.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `append!` command doesn't do what you think it does. You're thinking of the `push!` command.

The `append!` command *appends* two arrays together. Both arguments need to be arrays:

```
julia> append!(nodes, [Node("a", 42)])
1-element Array{Node,1}:
 Node("a",42)
```

No `length` implementing necessary
<sub>(that error was just telling you it tried to read the length of your array for the second argument and found something that was not an array.)</sub>

Comment: or, just use `push!` which is what it seems you're trying to do anyway.

Comment: it's interesting that `append!(v,1)` works though ... might be there for convenience, but according to the documentation for `append!` it shouldn't ... not sure if this should be reported as a bug or not ... :)

Comment: hm, I see, `append!(v,1)` works because `length(1)` returns `1`. ( `length(x::Number) = 1;` defined in numbers.jl line 14 )

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Base.append!(x::Array{Node,1}, val::Node) = push!(x, val)
```

then you get

```
append!(nodes, Node("a", 42))
1-element Array{Node,1}:
 Node("a",42)
```

you've got to explicitly create a function for this particular type as `append!` or any of the `Base` functions sometimes (or perhaps always I havent checked) wont accept `Any`